# Which Microsoft expression blend to use for VS 2012 on a windows 7 laptop

Tags: visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, windows-7-x64

Can someone please help me with my question? I am using VS2012 on my windows 7 laptop and the  Microsoft blend that automatically got installed along with VS2012 supports only windows 8. Which Microsoft expression blend version should I use to open my VS2012 solutions and work on them? 
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Expression Blend 4 works great.  According to the [website](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/eng/), they add back support for Silverlight and WPF in Update 2.  "In addition, Visual Studio 2012 Update 2 and later adds support for Silverlight and WPF editing, as well as SketchFlow."